# How to remove padding caused by font size?

Tags: html, css, input-field

In the following code, I have a challenge and I need your help.

There are 2 input fields next to each other.
The 2nd one on the right-hand side (green) is positioned a bit higher. It seems that there is padding or margin set at the bottom of the input field.
But I can't remove it.

When I set the font size of the 2nd input field same as the 1st input field,
the issue does not happen.

But the 2nd input field has to be bigger.

```html
<!doctype html>               
<html lang="en">            
<head>
<style>

#curSelButton {
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;

    font-size:15px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 2px;

    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
  }

#curSel {
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
    
    text-align: center;
    
    font-size:25px;

    background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
    font-weight: bold;    

    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;

    border-width: thin;   
    
  }
</style>

</head>

<body  >
    <table >     
        <tr >            
            <td >
                <input type="text" id="curSelButton"  readonly value="shuffle" > 
                <input type="text" id="curSel" value="ABC" readonly >                 
            </td>
        </tr>  
</body>
</html>
```

How can I position both input fields vertically at the same height, without changing the font site?

Many Thanks,
BM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top;` to both. By default they are aligned at the *baselines* of their texts.

```css
#curSelButton {
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#curSel {
  width: 60px;
  height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-width: thin;
}

#curSelButton,
#curSel {
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="curSelButton" readonly value="shuffle">
      <input type="text" id="curSel" value="ABC" readonly>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Johannes, 
I have tested all suggested solutions.

Your suggestion works with the minimum adjustment in my "original" code.

Answer (score 1):

You can put another td Element inside your tr and put your Button with class „curSel“ in it.

```
<tr >            
    <td >
       <input type="text" id="curSelButton"  readonly value="shuffle" > 
    </td>
    <td>
       <input type="text" id="curSel" value="ABC" readonly > 
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Thanks Jenyb32, 
I have tested all suggested solutions.

Your suggestion works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Use `div` insted of table and use CSS property `float:left` to align

```
<!doctype html>               
<html lang="en">            
<head>
<style>

  #curSelButton {
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
    font-size:15px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 2px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
 
    float:left;
 }

  #curSel {
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px; 
    text-align: center; 
    font-size:25px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
    font-weight: bold;    
    margin-left:3px;
    padding:0px;   
  
    float:left;
  }
</style>

</head>

<body  >
  

  <div>
    <input type="text"  id="curSelButton"  readonly value="shuffle" > 
  </div>

  <div>
    <input type="text" id="curSel" value="ABC" readonly >                 
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Arun, 
I have tested all suggested solutions.

Your suggestion works even with TD.

Answer (score 1):

Add `vertical-align: middle` to both the input fields.

```html
<!doctype html>               
<html lang="en">            
<head>
<style>

#curSelButton {
    font-size:15px;
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 2px;
  }

#curSel {                
    font-size:25px;
    background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0);
    font-weight: bold;    
    border-width: thin;           
  }

 #curSelButton, #curSel {
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 60px;
    height: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
 }

</style>

</head>

<body  >
    <table >     
        <tr >            
            <td >
                <input type="text" id="curSelButton"  readonly value="shuffle" > 
                <input type="text" id="curSel" value="ABC" readonly >                 
            </td>
        </tr>  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Rizeen, 
I have tested all suggested solutions.

Your suggestion works as well.

Comment: Hi Rizeen, in fact all provided solutions were good. I go with  Johannes solution, because with his approach I have no change in my code.

I now clicked on "arrow up" on your suggestion to indicate your proposal was helpful. Many Thanks.